# Return child type from a method on an abstract class or force two constructors on child

Tags: c#, .net, abstract-class, subclass

I have an abstract class TypedIdValueBase which has subclasses like UserId or ImageId.
I don't know how but I would like to have a Parse method (or a second constructor) and call it like that:

```
Guid valueG = Guid.NewGuid();

UserId userId1 = UserId.Parse(valueG ); //or new UserId(valueG )
ImageId imageId1 = ImageId.Parse(valueG ); // or new ImageId(valueG )

string valueS = "0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e";

UserId userId2 = UserId.Parse(valueS ); //or new UserId(valueS )
ImageId imageId2 = ImageId.Parse(valueS ); // or new ImageId(valueS )
```

I would like to force each child class to have that method but I really don't know how to handle it.
The best I had was something like that:

```
string value = "0f8fad5b-d9cb-469f-a165-70867728950e";
UserId userId = (UserId)UserId.Parse(value); //or new TypedIdValueBase.Parse<UserId>(value)
```

Does anyone have an idea on how to do something like that ?

Here is the code without traces of my attempts:

```
public abstract class TypedIdValueBase : IEquatable<TypedIdValueBase>
{
    public Guid Value { get; private set; }

    protected TypedIdValueBase(Guid value)
    {
        if (value == Guid.Empty)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Id value cannot be empty!");
        }

        Value = value;
    }
}

public class UserId : TypedIdValueBase
{
    public UserId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}

public class ImageId : TypedIdValueBase
{
    public ImageId(Guid value) : base(value)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: If you've made `value` a parameter for the constructor, what is the issue? What is wrong with the syntax `UserId userId = new UserId(value);` your example doesn't demonstrate the need for the parse method

Comment: I probably didnt' precise it enough but in the constructor of TypedIdValueBase  a Guid is required in parameter and in my question how to, it's a string and I would like to have or two different constructors mandatory for all of the subclasses or having a parse method or something to handle a string parameter